# A spanning tree as a result of running Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Just need to make sure about this:
When I run Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph, at the end I will have a spanning tree right ? (Not necessarily Minimum spanning tree)

So the difference between Dijkstra and PRIM/Kruskal that the later two algorithms will return a minimum spanning tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, with one condition - the graph should have a spanning tree from the source (i.e. - every vertex `v` in the graph has a path from the given source).

Also, as commented by @Henry - you should continue the algorithm until you found path to all vertices, and do not 'stop' once a target is reached.

Also note that Dijkstra's algorithm (and in general - shortest path solver) is defined for directed graphs, and MST is usually for undirected graphs.

(Note that it easy to define every undirected graph as a directed graph - by simply adding (u,v) and (v,u) for each edge {u,v} in the undirected graph)

Comment: The second condition is that you don't stop Dijkstra when you have reached the target.

Comment: @Henry AFAIK,this is an optimization and not the original algorithm, but this is a good point. thanks.